# Error when trying to view user defined function using F2 and source

Tags: r, rstudio

Running R 3.4.3, RStudio 1.1.383

I load function objects into my environment via the source function. In my code, I then write out the function name (same name in my global environment), and click F2. I get this error:

```
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘.GlobalEnv’
```

It opens a new tab in RStudio with the following:

```
# ERROR: Definition of function 'some_function' not found
# in namespace '.GlobalEnv'
```

However, if I click in the Global Environment pane to `View` the function, it opens up a new tab and shows the function code.

Any ideas?

Session Info:

```
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows Server >= 2012 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
    [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252
```

Edit:

Also getting the error with RStudio 1.1.423 that might be fixed here:

https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/1861

Comment: Same for me with RStudio 1.1.423. (but if the sourced file is already open in another tab F2 does work)

Comment: Yea, same experience when it's already open. I'm reading that it might be fixed for 1.1.423 here: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/1861

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer to what appears to be an RStudio bug, but  for an alternative work around, you might find just running the function name with no parens in your console to be a bit easier than clicking in the Global Environment pane. Ctrl + Enter will do that for you in Windows.

I'd report this over on the [RStudio github page](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues). I don't see it as an open issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... looks like they fixed this in a new version: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/1861.. Will try to download and follow up